# Counterexample for a theorem that is supposed to be true? Eigenvalues of A are nonnegative if and only if A^2=B, where A and B are symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra

There is a exercise that i have to prove, but i found a counterexample, what is wrong? (exercise 5.4.16 Linear Algebra: A Modern Introduction)

The theorem is:

- Let A and B be symmetric matrices.
- The eigenvalues of A are nonnegative if and only if A=B^2

My counterexample:

- A is a 2x2 identity matrix --> eigenvalues 1

  - A is symmetric
  - eigenvalue is nonnegative
- B = ( 9 1 , 1 4 ) (comma indicates new row)

  - B is symmetric
  - B^2 does not equal A, hence counterexample

Can i still prove the theorem or was my counterexample wrong?

Comment: I'd rather believe it's a joke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exercise states that

> If $A$ is a symmetric matrix, show that every eigenvalue of $A$ is non-negative if and only if $A = B^2$ for some symmetric matrix $B$

Hence the theorem only says that there exists some symmetric matrix $B$ s.t. $A = B^2$. Not that every symmetric $B$ satisfies this. In the case of $A$ being the identity, $B$ being the identity suffices.